# StreamListener Overwhelming TaskExecutor

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-stream, spring-rabbit

Two questions:

I have an `@StreamListener` reading from  a RabbitMQ channel.  I have a pool of 500 `ThreadTaskExecutor` instances to process the messages as they are read.

The problem is that `@StreamListener` is reading messages even if the pool is completely utilized.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.core.task.TaskRejectedException:
Executor [java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@4c15ce96
[Running, pool size = 500, active threads = 500, queued tasks = 1500,
completed tasks = 1025020]] did not accept task:
org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.async.SpanContinuingTraceCallable@4dc03919
```

Is there a way to configure `@StreamListener` so that it only reads from the queue if it has capacity?

In addition, this error trickles up to an `UndeclaredThrowableException`.  IO think its trying to throw the exception back to RabbitMQ so it reques the message.  However the end is this:

```
[WARN] o.s.a.r.l.ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler    
Execution of Rabbit message listener failed.  
org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.exception
    .ListenerExecutionFailedException: 
Retry Policy Exhausted
```

The final result is my message is lost.

Any suggestions for this second issue?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try `CallerRunsPolicy` for your `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor`? This way the task won't finish with error and the thread from the `SimpleMessageListenerContainer` will be busy to do the latest task for just arrived message. As far as you don't use `maxConcurrentConsumers` option not new concurrent listeners will be raised and the current one (`concurrentConsumers = 1` by default) will be busy and no new message is pulled from the Rabbit MQ.

See more info about listener container concurrency in the [Docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/2.0.2.RELEASE/reference/html/_reference.html#_simplemessagelistenercontainer). This way you may even reconsider your custom `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` solution and will fully rely on the built-in mechanism in the Framework.

The `maxConcurrency` option is exposed for the [RabbitMQ Binder Consumer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Elmhurst.RC3/reference/htmlsingle/#_rabbitmq_consumer_properties) as well.

Comment: You shouldn't use an executor unless you want to risk losing messages; the messages will be ack'd immediately after the handoff. As @artem said, use the container concurrency instead.

Comment: I am not fully understanding the answer, though it sounds like the solution I want.  The Docs at the link did not explain the concurrency model well.

Comment: The problem that `ListenerContainer` for AMQP is already async and multi-threaded. No reason to shift message to a separate thread pool. You need just increase `maxConcurrency` option for the `consumer` in binder configuration.